# How to show one place as active when embedding google maps?

Tags: google-maps, iframe, mymaps

I built a map for our website. There are different pages where we want to show a different places. Therefore i build this one map with all the needed places within. When i embed the card, it shows the summary of all pins in this map. Is there a way, to show one active pin, with its informations?

I searched for different parameters, with which you can alter the display of the card. But none of them is showing an explicit place.

This is a test map showing 4 pins. What should i do to show one chosen pin?
Hope this is understandable. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you want to "show one chosen pin" does it mean you have an info window for this marker and you want to display it?

If so, you can add unique ids for each infowindow and pass the chosen infowindow id to the url with url params such as https://mymapssite?chosenMarkerId=markerId

And then you can check if this param is given and if so do something like

```
document.getElementById("markerId").open(yourMapsRef, yourMarkerRef);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right that i want to show the info window for a marker. I just saw, that the code i used to put in my question is not visible at all. <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1bKkAjrLjx-GKdHLSMFgkOJzAxfttJBk_" width="640" height="480"></iframe> . I understand what your answer should do, but it does not work with mymaps because i set my own places..